# What are the alternatives of .txt?

Tags: filesystems, file-extension

For some reason, I can't save .txt files on my web server.

I have a text file hosted on my web server, but the ending is not .txt

I was wondering what ending should I choose, so that whoever sees that link would know that it  is a text file ?

<sup>I mean sure, I could do `file.asd` but basically I was wondering is there already some sort of standard (alike the `.txt`) so that generally when people see the file with that extension they would know (from past experience) that it is a text file?</sup>

Comment: I'd suggest that you try and investigate further why you can't save .txt files to the web server?  Failing that, why not just use .text as the extension?

Comment: Or no extension at all?

Comment: @slhck I've tried that but for some reason that doesn't work as well

Comment: @Stuart is there such a standard `.text` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `.text` — while not as common, it's clear to everyone what's in there. Services like filext.com also consider it an ASCII/plain-text file format.

I've seen `.text` used for Markdown (the formatting language also used on this site), but regular text is usually also valid Markdown, so no problem there.

---

Depending on your use, you can even skip the file extension. It's certainly popular with the Linux open-source folks, with file names such as `README` or `INSTALL`.

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with .NFO (as for "info") -> http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.nfo

or .ASC (for "ASCII") ->

> .asc, a computer filename extension sometimes used for text files, as an abbreviation to ASCII (also used by ASCII Armor in the programs GPG and PGP to convert binary data into ASCII)

from: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASC

Comment: .nfo is associated with some system information program on Windows.

Comment: yes, you're right. almost every common three letter extension is used for some other purpose. Even .TXT is used by Excel in tab-delimeted tables exports / imports. Browing inside any web server, I'd first think of .nfo being some info than being a backuped windows info file.

Comment: also, .nfo is primarily used by the warez community

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Now how do you know *that*?

Comment: misspent youth, naturally ;)